# Incompatible pointer type on NSDate compare

Tags: cocoa, compare, nsdate

The following code:

```
NSDate* date1 = [NSDate date];
NSDate* date2 = [NSDate date];
[date1 compare:date2];
[(NSDate*)[NSDate date] compare:date2];
[[NSDate date] compare:date2];
```

gives me "Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSDate *' to parameter of type 'NSNumber *'" for the last date comparison but not for the first two!

What is going on???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to cast to an NSDate because `+ (id)date` returns an id, not an NSDate.

Comment: Yeah. I came to the same conclusion once I realized that [(NSDate*)[NSDate date] compare:date2]; was working.  Makes sense.